# sql returning values in a list

Tags: sql, objective-c

I have an sql database in an Xcode project, i can read the data back no problem at all. The database has about 15,000 rows but one of the columns only has a handful of different entries.

What i want is a list of the different options in the list.

Currently I'm reading back the entire database and if my NSMuatableArray* doesn't contain the feedback adding it.

Is there anyway i can create the SQL syntax, so that only the different values are returned. Seems current way seems a waste of resources.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Hermanns example:
If the table has the name example and the field with the values "Level x" has the name useroptions.
If you want the list of the distinct values of column useroptions you can use the keyword `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT useroptions
FROM
    example;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the table has the name xyz and the field with the values "Level x" has the name abc then use

```
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE abc = "Level 3";
```

SQL is not case sensitive but the content of the string "Level 3" is.

If you want only those with Level something in it then use

```
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE abc LIKE "Level%";
```

Comment: hi there I've updated my question, the level1 - 2 - 3 indicate level of a group of people, they are user defined and could be anything, just out the 15000 records there will properly be about 5 - 10 different ones, what i want is this list but wondering if there is a better way of reading them back without having to read them all

Comment: Which list? The list of people of a certain group or the list of groups? Be a bit more specific! For the list of people do what I suggested. For a list of groups `select distinct abc from yxz'.

Comment: list of the different levels

Comment: Then go for @VMai's suggestion